# ViewModels talking to each other

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I've just created my first c# / XAML application using mvvmlight and I've tried to implement the MVVM pattern as best I can (WP8 app).  However, I've slowly morphed my code in to a certain style and I don't think its correctly implementing the pattern!  Any advice on how things are supposed to be would help enormously.

For example, using mvvmlight I am making heavy use of the ViewModelLocator.  Some of my viewmodels get created right away, like the SettingsViewModel  (there is a SettingsView).

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SettingsViewModel>(true);
```

And then elsewhere in my project, my other viewmodels will directly access this viewmodel for occasional information via a property or a method... like this;

```
mySetting = ViewModelLocator.SettingsStatic.GetSomeSetting(var);
```

My concern is that my viewmodels are talking to each other in this way more and more.  The issue with this is that they probably can't be tested independently now because they require or assume the existence of other viewmodels.

Any pointers here would be great!

EDIT:  Another example is having a PersonView, and the PersonViewModel has some helper methods for UI display.  In some cases I have other views that need to display this info.... and I use the viewmodellocator to get to them, rather than writing the helper methods again in the current viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in thinking that viewmodels being dependent on viewmodels is going to cause trouble.  When I need to have access to "global" settings in my app, I use an interface that can be injected in the constructor of the view model.  So, You can create an ISettingsService that contains the properties and methods you need.  You also create a design time setting service that mimics or fakes the data/properties of the ISettingsService Interface

then in your view model locator you use this:

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic) {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISettingsService, DesignSettingService>();
} else {
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISettingService, SettingService>();
}
```

Create the DesignSettingService and SettingService which both implement the ISettingsService.

As for you vewmodels,  the SimpleIOC will resolve/inject the required elements passed into the constructor of the class.  If you have a class/viewmodel called MyViewModel and it wanted to use the settingsservice then you would define the constructor like this:

```
private ISettingsService _SettingsAccess;

public New(ISettingsService SettingsService)
{
    _SettingsAccess = SettingsService;
    SettingProperty= _SettingsAccess.GetProperty;
}
```

This keeps the viewmodels decoupled as this service is resolved in the constructor, that way you can change the implementation of your ISettingsService without breaking every viewmodel that uses it.

I use a INavigationService to handle all the navigation events in my app, this allows me to cancel navigation based on another viewmodels properties without needing the other viewmodel to be directly called/referenced by the current one.

One view model should never directly call another view model.  Using this method you can pass as many "services" as are needed to the viewmodel.  Every viewmodel I use gets a dataservice that connects to my model in addition to the navigationservice.  Ie. A viewmodel that deals with people gets an IPeopleDataService where this service contains all the CRUD operations that affect the database.  That way I can change the people objects in the database and service functions without having to change the people viewmodel as well.

I hope this helps.